# How to filter string value in an attribute in RapidMiner

Tags: rapidminer

I have an attribute called `Age`. Some values in the `Age` Attribute is not integer at all. For example, `12W, 30Lo, Giraffe`. I want to filter out values that are not an integer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have mixed values, you should use the "Parse Numbers" operator to correctly handle the integer values. This operator has a parameter *unparsable value handling*, set this to "replace with missing", so all non-integer values are set to missing values.
Afterwards, depending on your use case, you can simply continue your workflow or filter your examples to remove the examples with a missing value in the Age column.